# Bind cache Django class based view response with parameter from request

Tags: python, django, caching

I want to cache my API response and bind it with parameter that is present in GET request.
The request looks like this:

```
GET /products?producent=some_company
```

Here is my simplified class:

```
class ProductsListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        producent = request.query_params.get("producent")
        cached_response = cache.get(f"response-products-{producent}", None)
        if not cached_response:
            queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
            page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page)
            response = self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

            cache.set(f"response-products-{producent}", response , timeout=20)
            return response

        return cached_response
```

But when I'm trying to cache the response I receive error:

```
django.template.response.ContentNotRenderedError: The response content must be rendered before it can be pickled.
```

Do you have any tips for me? I was searching here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/ when I was trying to figure out this. At first I tried the approach with `@cache_page` but it won't allow me to use the parameter from request, so I guess the way to go is Low level cache API.

Comment: `if not cached_products` or `if not cached_response` ? I think that it's the second one.

Comment: yes sorry, I edited it

Comment: the first cache_response this (cached_response = cache.get(f"response-products-{producent}", None) you give it `producent` did you define this variable ? you should first assign it a value before using it.

Comment: Why don't you cache the queryset and the template and want to cache all the response object ? You should try to cache the queryset and after the template portion where you loop trough the products

Comment: Try to convert the response to string before save it in cache.

Comment: The cache_page solution natively supports query parameters. Are you certain it’s not being cached?

Comment: @KeoniGarner I'm not sure but still I have to have the possibility to access the cache by name, because I want to clear the cache on the model save method when someone add the product for example.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually pretty descriptive. You must call `render()` on the response before attempting to pickle it into a cacheable format. The problem is: that will lead you on a rabbit hole to deconstruct the response and reconstruct from the cached data. IMO, you’d be better off caching the queryset. Nevertheless, this is what it would look like:

```py
class ProductsListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        producent = request.query_params.get("producent")
        response_triple = cache.get(f"response-products-{producent}", None)
        if not response_triple:
            queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
            page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page)
            response = self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

            response.render()

            if not response.status_code >= 400:
                # django 3.0 has no .items() method, django 3.2 has no ._headers
                if hasattr(response, '_headers'):
                    headers = response._headers.copy()
                else:
                    headers = {k: (k, v) for k, v in response.items()}
                response_triple = (
                    response.rendered_content,
                    response.status_code,
                    headers
                )
                cache.set(f"response-products-{producent}", response_triple, timeout=20)
        else:
            # build smaller Django HttpResponse
            content, status, headers = response_triple
            response = HttpResponse(content=content, status=status)
            for k, v in headers.values():
                response[k] = v
        if not hasattr(response, '_closable_objects'):
            response._closable_objects = []

        return response
```

Taken from: https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/blob/ecdf3a95d7f18ccf9cffa55809635c3715179605/rest_framework_extensions/cache/decorators.py#L63